# PostgreSQL. Improve indexes

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, indexing, postgresql-10

I have the following structure:

```sql
create table bitmex
(
  timestamp timestamp with time zone not null,
  symbol    varchar(255)             not null,
  side      varchar(255)             not null,
  tid       varchar(255)             not null,
  size      numeric                  not null,
  price     numeric                  not null,
  constraint bitmex_tid_symbol_pk
  primary key (tid, symbol)
);

create index bitmex_timestamp_symbol_index  on bitmex (timestamp, symbol);
create index bitmex_symbol_index  on bitmex (symbol);
```

I need to know the exact value of the quantity every time. So reltuples is not usable.

The table has more than 45,000,000 rows.

Running

```
explain analyze select count(*) from bitmex where symbol = 'XBTUSD';
```

gives

```
Finalize Aggregate  (cost=1038428.56..1038428.57 rows=1 width=8)
  ->  Gather  (cost=1038428.35..1038428.56 rows=2 width=8)
        Workers Planned: 2
        ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=1037428.35..1037428.36 rows=1 width=8)
              ->  Parallel Seq Scan on bitmex  (cost=0.00..996439.12 rows=16395690 width=0)
                    Filter: ((symbol)::text = 'XBTUSD'::text)
```

Running

```
explain analyze select count(*) from bitmex;
```

gives

```
Finalize Aggregate  (cost=997439.34..997439.35 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=6105.463..6105.463 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Gather  (cost=997439.12..997439.33 rows=2 width=8) (actual time=6105.444..6105.457 rows=3 loops=1)
        Workers Planned: 2
        Workers Launched: 2
        ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=996439.12..996439.14 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=6085.960..6085.960 rows=1 loops=3)
              ->  Parallel Seq Scan on bitmex  (cost=0.00..954473.50 rows=16786250 width=0) (actual time=0.364..4342.460 rows=13819096 loops=3)
Planning time: 0.080 ms
Execution time: 6108.277 ms
```

Why it did not use indexes?
Thanks

Comment: Please try `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, VERBOSE)`

Comment: Roughly how many rows have `symbol = 'XBTUSD'`? If most of the table has it, then the index isn't going to speed up anything and PG will skip it. Also, when was the table last `ANALYZED`? Stats being out of date can also cause this sort of thing. The second one doesn't use the index because you told it to *select all rows* and `COUNT` them.

Comment: updated with analyse

Comment: symbol = 'XBTUSD' // the most

Comment: @jpmc26 . . . That is not true.  The index is smaller to scan so it should be preferred over the original table.  The index is a covering index.

Comment: @GordonLinoff It's **100%** true. The extra disk reads incurred from reading the index for over 45 million rows is wasted if 44 million of them have to be read off disk in full anyway.

Comment: @jpmc26, should i drop all indexes instead of unique ?

Comment: i dropped. there is no difference in time and query plan

Comment: @alexya You should use indexes to optimize queries that have high selectivity (that require a small percentage of rows in the table). I don't know if any of your other queries fit that usage or not.

Comment: yes, true, but is there any chance to improve speed for counting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all rows have to be visited, an index scan is only cheaper if the table does not have to be consulted for most of the values found in the index.

Due to the way PostgreSQL is organized, the table has to be visited to determine if the entry found in the index is visible or not. This step can be skipped if the whole page is marked as “visible” in the *visibility map* of the table.

To update the visibility map, run `VACUUM` on the table. Maybe then an *index only scan* will be used.

But counting the number of rows in a table is *never* cheap, even with an index scan. If you need to do that often, it may be a good idea to have a separate table that only contains a counter for the number of rows. Then you can write triggers that update the counter whenever rows are inserted or deleted.

That will slow down the performance during `INSERT` and `DELETE`, but you can count the rows with lightning speed.

Comment: thank you, i've made separate table and update counters manually.